# IngerityError when Posting textarea content in django

Tags: python, html, django

I'm working on a simple project that requires a candidate to enter a description of his/herself. Since this requires lots of text, I use `models.TextField()` in models.py file and `<textarea>` tag in html.

In models.py

```
class Candidate(Person, models.Model):
    #Other fields
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

In Html

```
<!---some stuff up-->
<label for="candidate_description">Describe yourself</label>
<textarea id="candidate_description" placeholder="Description..."></textarea>
<!---some stuff below-->
```

views.py file

```
def regCandidate(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        candidate = Candidate(           
            description=request.POST.get('candidate_description'),
        )
        candidate.save()
    return render(request, 'Election/registerCandidate.html', {})
```

When I run the server and try to submit I get a `IntegerityError`. I have did some done some research and
found out the error is occurs when django receives a null value when it is required. I'm a beginner at django and I'm using custom forms. Can anyone help explain why django is receiving a `None` and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fields in form are passed on name and value basis. I am guessing that since you don't have a name attribute in Textarea, therefore that field is not passed to server.

Try adding a name attribute to the textarea field:

```
<textarea id="candidate_description" name="candidate_description" placeholder="Description..."></textarea>
```